# Margin after automic line break will be ignored

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, margin

The margin takes only affect for the first line (after automatic line break (depends on the size) will be ignored).

The HTML:

```
    <div class="BWForm_form-group">
        <div class="col-md-3 BWTextLeft">
            <label class="control-label" for="ContactPersonName">Name des Ansprechpartners<span style="color:red; display: inline-block;"> *</span></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <input class="text-box single-line input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Name of contact person field is required." id="ContactPersonName" name="ContactPersonName" value="" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="ContactPersonName" data-valmsg-replace="true"><span class="" for="ContactPersonName">The Name of contact person field is required.</span></span>
        </div>
          </div>
```

The css:

```
.field-validation-error {
color: #B94A48;
font-weight: bold;
margin: 15px;
}
```

The "BWForm_form-group" is inherited by the bootstrap class `form-group`."BWTextLeft" will only align:left.

What can I do to fix it ?
It looks like that [click](http://i58.tinypic.com/2s6ufpk.png) (the problem is right to my green arrow and vertical line)

Ty for helping

Comment: ok,done. Please take a look again

Answer (score 1):

oh ok remove the margin left from `field-validation-error` and then add a new class like to the container

```
 <div class="col-md-12 custom">
```

and the css looks like the below

```
 custom {
 margin:15px;
 }
```

demo example [here](http://www.bootply.com/EuFtSIK01z)

if you dont want to mess with the margins of the `col-md-12` then you should add a surrounding div like this

```
      <div class="col-md-12">
           <div class="custom">
              <div class="field-validation-error">
```

Comment: yes, its working fine- except that I use this "<div class="BWForm_form-group">" almost everywhere, when I remove the margin from ".field-validation-error" it will be missed somewhere else and I am looking for for a slution except adding "cust" to every starting container and by the way the margin inside cust will move the entire " <div class="col-md-12">" container and this will change the entire layout..